# ASIFormDataRequest POST does not working

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I have included all the necessary files in my app (.h and .m files as listed in [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions))
Then I manually added .m files to compile sources and I run my code.

I run my app but nothing went on my server. Server on scripts works fine because I use it in other android apps so it does not have a problem.

Here is the code I used in ViewDidLoad

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.myurl.php"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setPostValue:@"test@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"];
    [request setPostValue:@"5678" forKey:@"code"];
    [request setPostValue:@"Demo" forKey:@"table"];
    [request setPostValue:@"testname" forKey:@"name"];
```

Do I have to add anything?

Here is my imports:

```
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried starting your request?

```
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Thanks! that was it! I knew that something was missing but the tutorial i saw didn't write it down. is there any method that is being called after the request is finished?